# Javascript promise handle 404

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest, promise

I have this code:

```
promise.success(function (data) {

            //do something

}).fail(function() {
    //handle 404, don't let the browser log it
});
```

The url is fine, but if the user doesn't exist, the api is returning a 404 error (on purpose).

Browser logs the error... is it possible to avoid it and display different message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser's dev tools will always display the failed request, however you can recover from a rejected promise by returning a value in the "fail" callback.

See [here](http://www.mattgreer.org/articles/promises-in-wicked-detail/#recovering-from-rejection).

**UPDATE**

```
promise.success(function (data) {
    //do something
}).fail(function() {
    return true; // or return { error: true, reason: "some reason" };
});
```

Comment: this is correct.  The browser is what handles logging the non-success values (404, 500, etc...) not the JS library you're using.  Can you return something other than a 404 (such as a 204 - No Content, but browser handles this as successful response).  You can also make your API return a standardized object that has a success variable in it and check for that.

Or you just ignore the 404 line in the console...

Comment: Understood! Thank you very much!